# How to ignore few elements in div class while webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a website and I want to ignore few elements with in div class

```
r = requests.get(
            f"https://www.ranger5g.com/forum/threads/pre-collision-assist.3239")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

data=[]

for div in soup.findAll("div", class_="bbWrapper"):
            try:
                div.find('blockquote', class_="bbCodeBlock bbCodeBlock--expandable bbCodeBlock--quote").extract()                  
            except AttributeError:
                 pass  
            try:
                div.find('bbCodeBlock-content').extract()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            try:
                div.find("aside", class_="message-signature").extract()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            result = [div.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
            data.append(result)
```

my output of data[2] should give as follows

```
Subaru dealer by me uses an orange construction cone for demo. Find one and try it. Won’t hurt anything if it doesn’t work.
```

But it gives whatever is there in previous message. How could I ignore element in class_="message-signature", How can I get this. Thank you in advance

Comment: using the parent-child relationships in beautifulsoup is likely a better option then using logic statements.

Comment: Use css and :not pseudo: `.aside:not(.message-signature)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def Main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.findAll(
        "div", class_="bbCodeBlock-expandContent")[2].get_text(strip=True)
    print(target)


Main("https://www.ranger5g.com/forum/threads/pre-collision-assist.3239/")
```

Output:

```
Subaru dealer by me uses an orange construction cone for demo. Find one and try it. Won’t hurt anything if it doesn’t work.
```

Comment: This is not taking into consideration all the comments. There are many comments missing